# How to put classic load balancers behind an AWS application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

AWS has launched application load balancer which can do path based routing. Is it possible to put classic load balancers behind the application load balancer.

Example: 
Lets say we have 2 classic load balancers. Application Load Balancer will route traffic to first classic load balancer for all url like application-load-balancer/front* and will route traffic to second classic load balancer for all url like application-load-balancer/backend*

Currently, seems like we can only put hosts behind an application load balancer. Is it possible to put load balancer behind an application load balancer?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

Both the Classic Load Balancer and the new Application Load Balancer can only point to **Amazon EC2 instances**.

However, you can achieve exactly what you desire through the use of an **Application Load Balancer** on its own:

- Create **Target Groups** (such as `frontend` and `backend`) and add your desired instances to each group -- this is similar to each Classic Load Balancer you wanted to use
- Create the **Application Load Balancer** and configure it to point appropriate paths to each Target Group

You can think of the Application Load Balancer as being multiple Classic Load Balancers, each with a different path.

Comment: The reason why we are looking to put classic load balancers behind an application load balancer is that 2 classic load balancers are managed through separate elastic beanstalk application. And as number of ec2 hosts will scale up and down depending on traffic it will become difficult to add/remove them directly from behind application load balancer.